# I got a strange error when printing a matrix and passing it to various functions

Tags: c, matrix

I got this error

*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Abortado (núcleo despejado)
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Abortado (núcleo despejado)

when i choose a value from line 8 example like 8A or 8C.
but the function play still makes what need but when the board is printed it doesn't print line 8 like it should.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 

//void init_board(char board[8][8]){
//    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
//           board[i][j]='.';
//        }
//    }
//    board[3][3]='o';
//    board[4][4]='o';
//    board[3][4]='x';
//    board[4][3]='x';
//}
void init_board(char board[8][8]){
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
           board[i][j]='.';
        }
    }
    board[3][3]='o';
    board[4][4]='o';
    board[3][4]='x';
    board[4][3]='x';
    board[5][2]='x';
    board[5][3]='o';
    board[6][1]='x';
    board[3][0]='o';
    board[3][1]='o';
    board[4][1]='x';
    board[2][5]='o';
    board[2][4]='x';
}

void print_board(char board[8][8]){
    printf("  A B C D E F G H");
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d ",i+1);
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            printf("%c ",board[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
int count_flips_dir(char board[8][8],int line, char col,int delta_line,int delta_col,char color){
    int i;
    if(board[line+delta_line][col+delta_col]=='.'){
        return 0;
    }
    for(i=0;board[line+delta_line][col+delta_col]!=color;i++){
        line=line+delta_line;
        col=col+delta_col;
        if(board[line+delta_line][col+delta_col]=='.'){
        return 0;
        }
    }
    return i;
        
}
int flanked(char board[8][8],int line,char col,char color ){
    int NN = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,-1,0,color);
    int ND = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,-1,1,color);
    int NE = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,-1,-1,color);
    int SS = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,1,0,color);
    int SD = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,1,1,color);
    int SE = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,1,-1,color);
    int D = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,0,1,color);
    int E = count_flips_dir(board,line,col,0,-1,color);
    return NN+NE+ND+SD+SE+SS+E+D;
}
void changeboard(char board[8][8],int line, char col,int delta_line,int delta_col,char color){
    int i;
    for(i=0;board[line+delta_line][col+delta_col]!=color;i++){
        board[delta_line+line][delta_col+col]=color;
        line=line+delta_line;
        col=col+delta_col;      
    }
}
void change(char board[8][8],int line,char col,char color){
    if (count_flips_dir(board,line,col,-1,0,color)>0){
        changeboard(board,line,col,-1,0,color);
    }
    if (count_flips_dir(board,line,col,-1,1,color)>0){
        changeboard(board,line,col,-1,1,color);
    }
    if (count_flips_dir(board,line,col,-1,-1,color)>0){
        changeboard(board,line,col,-1,-1,color);
    }
    if (count_flips_dir(board,line,col,1,0,color)>0){
        changeboard(board,line,col,1,0,color);
    }
    if (count_flips_dir(board,line,col,1,-1,color)>0){
        changeboard(board,line,col,1,-1,color);
    }
    if (count_flips_dir(board,line,col,1,1,color)>0){
        changeboard(board,line,col,1,1,color);
    }
    if (count_flips_dir(board,line,col,0,1,color)>0){
        changeboard(board,line,col,0,1,color);
    }
    if (count_flips_dir(board,line,col,0,-1,color)>0){
        changeboard(board,line,col,0,-1,color);
    }
}
void play(char board[8][8],int line,char col,char color){
    board[line][col]=color;
    change(board,line,col,color);
    print_board(board);
}
int main(){
    int l;
    char c;
    char board[8][8];
    init_board(board);
    print_board(board);
   
    printf("\nEscolha a sua Jogada: ");
    scanf("%d %c", &l, &c);
    c=c-'A';
    l=l-1;
    
    //teste função count_flips_dir
    //printf("%d",count_flips_dir(board,l,c,1,1,'o'));
    
    //teste funçao flanked
    //printf("\n%d",flanked(board,l,c,'o'));
    if (board[l][c]=='.'){
        if(flanked(board,l,c,'o')>0){
            play(board,l,c,'o');
        }
    }
    
    
return 0;

}
```

Comment: It means you have a memory overflow or some other memory corruption bug. Use basic debugging techniques to try and find it. Remove all the code and add a bit back at a time to try and narrow down where the problem is. Use a tool like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) to help you find the problem.

Comment: The scanf is working just fine i test it before the problem it is just the printing of the board that print less a  line when a chosee a value from line 8 and pass it to function play

Answer (score 1):

The function `change_board` has an infinite loop and overwrites board cells beyond the board boundaries, causing undefined behavior, in your case corrupting stack memory.

The logic is incorrect. You should test boundary cases so `delta_line+line` and `delta_col+col` stay in the proper range [0..7] in `count_flips_dir` too.

Comment: Thanks for the help i solve it by puting the loop inside 2 if sections controling the delta_line and delta_col